# Accords après "la ou les"

Tags: grammaire, accord, pluriel

J'ai la phrase suivante :

> La (les) position(s) suivante(s) de la commande a (ont) dû
>   malheureusement être annulée(s) :

Sous cette phrase se trouvent X articles (de 1 à N).

Je trouve la construction lourde, et pensais la remplacer par le pluriel, même s'il n'y a qu'un seul article.
A noter que ce texte est destiné aux pays francophones, principalement, la France, la Belgique, la Suisse et le Canada.

Est-ce correct ou y a-t-il une meilleure construction ?

Comment: Réponse courte : a priori tu dois employer le pluriel si l'un des éléments est au pluriel. Réponse plus précise : https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/accord-avec-ou-et-ni.php et http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.8.3

Comment: À tout hasard, c'est pas informatique et il y a pas moyen de coder un message différent si il n'y a qu'un article ?

Comment: C'est en effet dans le cadre d'un programme informatique, cependant les phrases sont stockées dans une base de données. Séparer pluriel et singulier en 2 entrées est une possibilité que j'aborderai le temps venu (j'ai 4 langues à gérer pour l'instant, et bien plus dans un futur proche). La proposition de @SimonDéchamps en utilisant "la ou les" puis accordant au pluriel me plaît beaucoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bof... dans le doute mets tout au pluriel. On peut considérer que l'unicité fait partie du pluriel. Les gens qui iront sur ton site devraient comprendre. Donc :

```
Les positions suivantes de la commande ont dû malheureusement être annulées :
```

NB: "positions" ? ou  "propositions" ?

Comment: En effet, c'est vers cette solution que je vais certainement m'orienter. Je n'aime pas non plus le terme "positions", "articles" conviendrait mieux. Le texte vient d'une traduction de version allemande (pas ma traduction), il reste parfois des mots ou des tournures de phrases qui ne passent pas.

Answer (score 3):

Rien à voir mais si tu inverses "dû" et "malheureusement" je trouve déjà la phrase moins lourde ;)

Comment: Excellente suggestion, merci !